# WSO2 AM-Analytics worker error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using APM-Analytic 2.6, I configured database (Oracle 12c) as the following docs (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#standardsetup).
My worker has run few days, then has occurred the errors:

---

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Dumping heap to /d01/WSO2/wso2am-2.6.0/wso2am-analytics-2.6.0/wso2/worker/logs/heap-dump.hprof ...
Unable to create /d01/WSO2/wso2am-2.6.0/wso2am-analytics-2.6.0/wso2/worker/logs/heap-dump.hprof: File exists
Exception in thread "MVStore background writer nio:/d01/WSO2/wso2am-2.6.0/wso2am-analytics-2.6.0/wso2/worker/database/WSO2_CARBON_DB.mv.db" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.h2.mvstore.Page.create(Page.java:122)
        at org.h2.mvstore.Page.createEmpty(Page.java:101)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.<init>(MVMap.java:75)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.openReadOnly(MVMap.java:1156)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.getMetaMap(MVStore.java:527)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.openMapVersion(MVStore.java:409)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.openVersion(MVMap.java:1133)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.rewrite(MVMap.java:780)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.compactRewrite(MVStore.java:1918)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.compact(MVStore.java:1810)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.writeInBackground(MVStore.java:2512)
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:2720)
[2019-11-12 22:16:27,292] ERROR {org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.Scheduler} - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[2019-11-12 22:16:34,477] ERROR {org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.Scheduler} - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "MVStore background writer nio:/d01/WSO2/wso2am-2.6.0/wso2am-analytics-2.6.0/wso2/dashboard/database/MESSAGE_TRACING_DB.mv.db" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[2019-11-12 22:17:12,793]  INFO {org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.mgwfile.task.MGWFileCleanUpTask} - Uploaded API Usage data in the db will be cleaned up to : 2019-11-07 22:16:25.014
[2019-11-12 22:17:24,591] ERROR {org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.Scheduler} - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[2019-11-12 22:17:52,813] ERROR {org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.Scheduler} - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[2019-11-12 22:17:45,545] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.deployment.engine.internal.SchedulerTask} - Error occurred while scanning deployment repository java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Please let me know if you have any other solutions in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you are using H2 as the database for Analytics as well.
But since there going to be loads of data persisting in the database related to analytics, it is always recommended to use one of the following (Otherwise analytics instance could simply fail due to inconsistency of handling loads of data by the H2 database);

- Postgres 9.5 and later
- MySQL 5.6
- MySQL 5.7
- Oracle 12c
- MS SQL Server 2012
- DB2

You could follow the doc [1] (Check the standard-setup tab and specially the database configuration steps) and make the proper deployment.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#ConfiguringAPIMAnalytics-Step4-Configurethedatabases

Cheers!

Comment: I configured APIM_ANALYTICS_DB, WSO2AM_MGW_ANALYTICS_DB and WSO2_PERMISSIONS_DB to Oracle, but the problem still occurs :(